# How To Resolve Issue With Google User Data Policy

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, policy, privacy-policy

My app keeps getting rejected from Google Play, for more than 3 times now. Below is the message I keep getting from Google Play console.

> APK HAS A PRIVACY POLICY​ BUT IT IS NOT ADEQUATE
>
> Privacy Policy in Play Distributed App Your app is uploading users'
> Contact list and Media information to without posting a privacy policy
> in Play Distributed App.

Below is also a link to the privacy policy for the app. I don't know exactly what am missing.
[Privacy Policy](https://waladigital.io/privacy-policy)

I know it may be hard to find time to go through the whole privacy policy so below is a section that discuss what information is collected.

> Information Collection and Use
>
> For a better experience, while using our Service, we may require you
> to provide us with certain personally identifiable information,
> including but not limited to Name, email address, phone number, date
> of birth, gender, device contacts list. The information that we
> request will be retained by us and used as described in this privacy
> policy.
>
> For a better experience, while using our services, we collect
> information about how you use our products and services. We use that
> information to provide you with products and services, to help keep
> WalaDigital – Blood Donation more relevant to you.
>
> Personal Information: We collect personal information from you such
> as;
>
> First and last name Email address Phone number Date of birth Gender
> Blood type and genotype Device Information. We collect information
> from and about the devices you use to access WalaDigital – Blood
> Donation, including:
>
> Information about your device, operating system, language and device
> uuid. Your device address book, if you’ve chosen to share it with us.
> Data you provide us is transmitted off your device unto our servers
> for the purposes of improving your user experience and also for how
> the application works.
>
> For instance, your profile photos or images you capture are
> transmitted off the device unto our servers to best serve you via our
> secure Wala Digital API Services.
>
> This transmission process is highly secured to protect your data. All
> data such as contact address list and photos are not shared with any
> third party.
>
> Although, the app does use third-party services that may collect
> information used to identify you.
>
> Link to the privacy policy of third-party service providers used by
> the app.

NOTE: There is a privacy policy in the app as well during signup.

Comment: Add the privacy policy in the app as well before you start collecting the data.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Its also added in the app as well.

Comment: Is the link to the privacy policy also in the play store listing page details? You have to put the link on Google Play too, not just in the app. Aside from that, Google is probably the only one who can answer this. There is a high chance it's an AI that is rejecting your app.

Answer (score 0):

A more clear Privacy Policy that discloses the sensitive personal data you collect and how you handle that data might be required.

For example, Google Play considers contacts and media as sensitive data which are subject to sensitive permissions policies [1]:

- Declare runtime sensitive permissions
- Integrate consent screens before asking for contacts, media data (see Prominent Disclosure & Consent)

  [image]
- Comply with Personal and Sensitive User Data policy and Google Play requirements for a Privacy Policy [2]:

  - Disclosing the types of personal and sensitive user data your app accesses, collects, uses, and shares; and any parties with which any personal or sensitive user data is shared.
  - Secure data handling procedures for personal and sensitive user data.
  - The developer’s data retention and deletion policy.

[1] https://developer.android.com/games/develop/permissions

[2] https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10144311?hl=en